# Why is state not getting updated in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect, use-state

I have a signup page in react wherein after signup ,the user is redirected to the homepage.I want to make my homepage a protected route where only loggedin users can enter.

My code for signup:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleSignup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
        setcurrentuser(user);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          navigate('/homepage');
        },3000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  }
```

after receiving user object from firebase, I have set the state for the user and as state takes time to get updated,I have used a timeout of 3s to navigate to the homepage.Still when I log the user object I get undefined.

Code for homepage:

```
 const Homepage = ({user,username,setusername}) => {
    console.log(user);
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    // useEffect(()=>{
    //     if(user=={} || !user)
    //     navigate('/signup');
    // })
    return(
           <>
           ...some code here
           </>)}
export default HomePage
```

The state is in the app component and signup component sets the state for the user object using the props it receives.
Homepage gets the props from the app component.

Comment: any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Seems like StackOverflow is dead....Haven't received responses to my questions for the past few days.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `setcurrentuser` function? because thats where you set state right?

Comment: Lets start troubleshooting this thing mate,

Comment: is `setcurrentuser` a hook or custom function?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to this, to use useContext instead of props. As its easier and more efficient.
Here is a link to a documentation to help you out.
Visit https://betterprogramming.pub/react-hooks-and-forms-dedb8072763a

Comment: I know it's a better way, but I currently do not have much time for this task and want to get it done.

Comment: Instead of using props you can store the data received from firebase in a local storage ...localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data)); ... Then you can just get the item in any components you wan to use them ... localStorage.getItem('items'); ... And use it

Answer (score 0):

Okey,
first of all inorder not to get undefined or null on that protected `Homepage`
you need some way of accessing a user data, those obtained after login,

and primary good place to store those so they'll be accessible across the entire site is on `localStorage` with this code and once you navigate to `Homepage`
you'll go to take your stored user on your `localStorage`

**Note1:** `localStorage` store primitive data with no problem, but objects needs to be stringified first, we'll get to that soon,

**Note2:** waiting 3 seconds to navigate to another page is awful alot of time in user experience, i wont suggest that, if you want to wait for some event to occur so as to trigger another event and you dont have other way, you can use `javascript's` event loop trick of zero second which places the function/event needed to wait on just `nextTick` of event loop. which is done by writing

```
   setTimeout(()=>{
          navigate('/homepage');
        },0); //Note that 0 second, that will place navigation on nextTick of eventLoop
```

Now if Note2 is confusing just dont worry, lets get to your problem,

**Signup:**

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleSignup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
       //Edited place
        if(user){ //check if we got user object right
           localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));//store in global storage
           navigate('/homepage');//let go to homepage :)
        }//End of Edited 
         
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  }
```

**Right on Homepage area**

```
const Homepage = () => {
    //console.log(user);This wont give you your user so just remove it from the props above
    const navigate=useNavigate();
      useEffect(()=>{
         let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
       if(user){
           //then we have user
           //bring her up from object stringifying..
          user = JSON.parse(user);
          //get her details if needed
          const {username, email,...} = user
       }else{ //not signed so go back
          navigate('/signup');
       }
     })
    return(
           <>
           ...some code here
           </>)
     }
export default HomePage
```

Comment: but my user comes from firebase authentication,why use localStorage in that case

Comment: Then firebase supposed to have central data storage system on place, i havent used firebase my bad